# size of tensor product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

In a recent intro to homological algebra, someone drew an analogy between tensoring and the geometric operation of intersecting varieties. (I didn't understand this as I don't know algebraic geometry.) But it left me with the following intuitive question:

> Why does taking the tensor product of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules sometimes make things bigger and sometimes smaller?

Examples:

- The tensor of free modules of finite rank is free of bigger rank.
- The tensor of the infinitely generated non-free module $\mathbb{Q}$ with itself is again itself.
- $\mathbb{Z}/2\otimes \mathbb{Z}/3 = 0$. In general, the tensor of modules has annihilator something like the ideal sum of annihilators.

Also contrastingly, the intersection of submodules $2\mathbb{Z}$ and $3\mathbb{Z}$ within $\mathbb{Z}$ is their ideal product, which is $6\mathbb{Z}$, set-theoretically smaller. But isomorphic to both inputs as a module.

Is there a "geometric" way of thinking that covers all of this?

Comment: The tensor product kills of two modules M and N kills things that have "incompatible" torsions — in Z/2\otimes Z/3 elements are killed by 2 and by 3, so they have no option but that of being zero. Incompatibility is like tango, it takes two, and thus depending what's in each of the two modules and how well they play together they either live and multiply or get killed.

Comment: For abelian groups there is another product, the torsion product (you will find an explanation in Maclane's book *Homology*) that records the *mixed torsion* of the two groups, more or less, the compatibilities I hinted above. It is instructive to look at its construction.

Comment: You might add $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}=0$ to your list of examples.

Comment: The way I think of tensor products is: to get $A\otimes B$, you do the same thing to $B$ as you need to do to $\mathbb{Z}$ to get $A$ (a precise statement of this idea is the Eilenberg-Watts theorem, which says this characterizes tensor products if "thing" means "colimit-preserving functor").  So in particular, if $A$ is "smaller" than $\mathbb{Z}$ you can expect $A\otimes B$ to be "smaller" than $B$.

Comment: This is not suitable as an answer at the intro-to-homological-algebra level, hence a comment. One *could* think of taking the tensor product as the two step procedure: (1) take the derived tensor product, which makes things "bigger" (for example once you replace everything by free/projective resolutions) (2) ignore everything but the degree $0$ part, which makes things smaller.